# How to determine the relationship between classes?

Tags: python

I have two classes:

```
class A(object):
    """Instance of this class must by only one"""

    def some_function(self):
         print "A function"

    [... other functions ...]


class B(object):
    """Many instances of this class"""

    [... functions ...]
```

And I want to init only one object of class A from class B, I write this:

```
class B(object):
    a_instance = A()
    b_instances = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        B.a_instance.some_function()
        B.b_instances.append(self)
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def update(self):
        print "Update instance"

    @classmethod
    def super_function(self):
        print "My super B function"
        for instance in B.b_instances:
             instance.update()
```

Is this correct?

And second question: How to call "super_function" from instance of class A?

Comment: *"How to call "super_function" from instance of class A?"* – `B.super_function()`. There is no other relationship from `A` to `B`.

Comment: Why do `super_function` is a `classmethod`? It makes me suspicious that it suggests something other than you would like to accomplish.... Please elaborate what is your final goal, or provide better example.

Comment: I added additional code. super_function update every instance of class B

Comment: If you would explain what you're practically trying to implement, we could suggest a proper solution. As is, this seems a bit iffy.

Comment: Class A listening messages of RabbitMQ, and if it receives must call for each instance of the class B function update. Class B is tornado websocket class.